# Is there a findAndModify that returns many documents in MongoDb Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using `MongoDb Morphia for Java` and I want to pessimistically lock many documents with one command. I am familiar with the `findAndModify` method, which will find and update one document. **Is there a method that will do the same for multiple documents?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAndModify()` only works with a single document as defined by the server's behavior.  If you're wanting to update multiple documents in one all-or-nothing block, you might consider using a [transaction](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.3/transactions.html).